# Xbox 360 with RGH mod and internet

Tags: xbox-360, hardware, homebrew

I've already bought Xbox 360S which was modified by RGH. I did some research on the web and I know that Xbox Live is unavailable with this kind of mod.
But how about other functionalities of X360 which use internet connection. Will it be possible to collect achievements on my account and share them like these from PlayStation (for example on the PSNProfiles site)?

I'm leaving out the multiplayer aspect entirely because I'm more of a gamer focused on single-player games. I'm more concerned with how severely limited social functionality will be due to the presence of RGH.